# How to insert table data into a textarea and delete to much space between words

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a table that I want to copy and want to insert that data into a text area.
I did the same thing with a table before.

The first table that works looks like this when copied and insert in textarea

[image]

12qabYmEaRNJRmFCpsqfmHDBQ5fFu2U2g6  0.00019553 
1PZfsRZLZZtoNyNPpTQSRZPXfYCYyg1Z7   0.00011000 
3EEwMEc42pQScDWtSyEhZf56wq6iQsmk5e  0.00007234

So as you see no problem to take that data via PHP trim function.

But the second table looks like this when copied:

[image]

0x284254f26926Da572db7264758558110B8F9BE0e 
0.00066324
0.00016581
181
2020-05-03 14:31:55 
0xd274df933df55045db98b993a495e5907684a647 
0.00005247
0.00001311

I tried to build a little js to eliminate the space between the strings on the second textarea but it doesnt work:

```
function delete_space() {
        var text = $('textarea#mytextarea').val();
        var text2 = text.replace(/  +/g, ' ')
        if (text2 != "") {
            console.log(text2);
        }
    }
```

The rows should contain as a row on not split in multiple as you can see.
Any suggestions for my code that will looks like this:

0x284254f26926Da572db7264758558110B8F9BE0e 0.00066324 0.00016581 181 2020-05-03 14:31:55

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Hi! You are trying to select the text with Jquery or pure js? The way you selected it is Jquery and if you aren't importing the script it won't work. To use pure JS you can use getElementbyId or one of those.

Comment: I have imported jquery, but the script doesnt work right.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the code in pure JavaScript it seems to work OK.

```
function delete_space() {
        var text = document.getElementById('mytextarea').value;
        var text2 = text.replace(/  +/g, ' ')
        if (text2 != "") {
            console.log(text2);
        }
    }
```